# Xpages an issue with jar file

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I've created a "*.jar" file with Intellij IDEA and added to IBM Notes Domino 9 with Code -- Jars -- Import Jar.
I can see my packages in classes which stored in "Code -- Java") but i have an error when i try to use my jar in xpages code:

I have a simple code on my test xpage:

```
importPackage(com.ibm.ibateam.sources);
var area = new Area("first");
getComponent("label1").setValue(area.getUnid());
```

but this code throws exception:

```
Script interpreter error, line=2, col=16: [ReferenceError] 'Area' not found
1: importPackage(com.ibm.ibateam.sources);
-> 2: var area = new Area("first");
3: getComponent("label1").setValue(area.getUnid());
```

I've tried everything with Java Build Path but nothing works.

I also tried use information from this link:

http://www.xpagetips.com/2012/06/extending-your-xpages-applications-with.html

but move to "WEB-INF/lib/..." didn't help

I know I can add my jar to "...Notes\jvm\lib\ext)" or to eclipse plugins but I don't like this solution because I want to store my jar in notes database.

Comment: And the fully qualified name for Area is com.ibm.ibateam.sources.Area? Is the constructor (with a String as parameter) public?

Comment: yes, constructor is public and fully qualified name is correct

Comment: And the fully qualified name for Area is com.ibm.ibateam.sources.Area?

Comment: yes com.ibm.ibateam.sources.Area

Comment: Use XPages Log File Reader to see if there are any other errors in the xpages log files.

Comment: maybe something wrong with my jar file, I've tried to build without shade plugin and relocation dependencies and don't have any exceptions any more

Comment: Have you tried using the full name for the class ?

 var area = new com.ibm.ibateam.sources.Area("first");

Comment: Do you think we will have some different result with using full class name?

Comment: Try modifying your java.policy file to allow all operations. It might be a security issue.

Comment: This might be trivial, but are you making sure to build the project?

Comment: I am as all domino developers, clean and build all the time, and also reopen designer... it's our initial skills:)

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I have had this problem several times before. And the full path has solved this for me.