# how to create valid jar for domino 9

Tags: java, maven, lotus-domino

I've tried to make my own .*jar file to avoid package conflicts in Domino, but I haven't come to any success.

I have xpage with a button and a label, and on a button's click event I have this code:

```
importPackage(com.ibm.parkplatz.sources);
var area = new Area("The first floor");
getComponent("label1").setValue(area.getName());
```

After I press the button I have this Exception:

```
Script interpreter error, line=2, col=16: [ReferenceError] 'Area' not found
     1: importPackage(com.ibm.parkplatz.sources);
->   2: var area = new Area("The first floor");
     3: getComponent("label1").setValue(area.getName());
```

Links to my pom.xml and jar file:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxrNKasTcWWFUnBvQjUxQWxCR1U (pom.xml)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxrNKasTcWWFd3czSXEtbnFDaDA (jar)
```

I have no idea why I have so many problems with importing jar file to Domino 9.
Maybe anybody knows what should I do to make valid jar with dependencies for Domino 9.

Now I just re-import my jar to database and had a different exception:

```
 Script interpreter error, line=2, col=16: Error while calling java constructor 'com.ibm.parkplatz.sources.Area(string)' (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException).
     1: importPackage(com.ibm.parkplatz.sources);
->   2: var area = new Area("The first floor");
     3: getComponent("label1").setValue(area.getName());
```

Comment: It would be better to edit your original question http://stackoverflow.com/q/40373716/2065611 and not to create this new question.

Comment: Thank you for advice, i'll do it next time. Sorry for that.

Comment: Nobody knows how to do valid jar with shaded dependencies for Domino?